# enabling error reporting fixed http 500 error on windows server

Tags: php, http, http-status-code-500

I have a web application programmed in php hosted on windows server which was working great until recently he encountered "http 500 internal server error" only on 1 php page which was basically retrieving and displaying information from database. i checked to see what can be the possible reasons for that error to happen. when i tried to generate the same error after including  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in that php page, the page started working.
and I dont know what was the reason which was causing that http 500 error to generate.

if anyone has idea about this issue then please share the knowledge, it would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the php_error.log, if you do not know the location, open php.ini and find the path, or enable it if not enabled. Then log the error.